# IIS can't load 64 bit DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, unmanaged

I have a .NET C# WebAPI application which is meant to run on IIS. The app loads an external 64 bit DLL. When I debug on VS2015 everything is fine, but I had to set this checkbox in order to make it work:

[image]

Now, I deployed the application on a Windows7 VM running IIS version 7.5 and I get the same error as if I haven't set that checkbox on VS2015. Is there any equivalent setting in IIS in order to force 64 bit mode?

Comment: Have you checked the setting in the application pool?

Comment: @DavidG what settings? if you mean the 32bit mode yes, it's set to false

Comment: Just to be 100% sure: Is it a 64 Bit Windows 7 Installation?

Comment: If you compile your WebAPI targeting 64bit platform then you should be good.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé yes, 64 bit windows 7 enterprise N

Comment: And what is the error message you get?

Comment: unfortunately they decided to use messagebox() to display errors instead of returning an error code. The popup is originating inside the dll and on a plain IIS I have no way to see it. I can enable the logs and I'll tell you what I get

Comment: @PankajKapare tried but no cigar

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini You don't have any other non-64-bit websites on the IIS server *not* running in 64-bit mode with the **same** Application Pool, do you? You cannot run mixed architecture applications on the same Application Pool, I'd recommend building a new Application Pool out of the box and start testing with it.

Comment: Does dll save files on server? Try running application as Admin on server.  You may not have the credentials to run dll on server.

Comment: So what is the actual error message?

Comment: finally I discovered the DLL is loaded but it's unable to connect to a local service I have. I think it's using a TCP/IP connection on localhost, IIS is blocking the connection (I guess)